# Stream Icecast using Gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer

I'm designing a program to stream an icecast server ([radio.clarkson.edu](http://radio.clarkson.edu:8000/live.m3u)). Ultimately it will be written in Python3, but for now I'm using gst-launch to test the pipeline. I've been working on Debian Jessie and using gstreamer-1.0. Using a file on Wikimedia, I was able to play pretty easily using:

```
url=https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0c/Muriel-Nguyen-Xuan-Korsakov-Flight-of-the-bumblebee.flac.oga
gst-launch-1.0 -v souphttpsrc location =$url ! decodebin ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! alsasink
```

Running the same commands with my stream, I get the output:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstTypeFindElement:typefind.GstPad:src: caps = text/uri-list
Missing element: text/uri-list decoder
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0: Your GStreamer installation is missing a plug-in.
Additional debug info:
gstdecodebin2.c(3977): gst_decode_bin_expose (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0:
no suitable plugins found
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstTypeFindElement:typefind.GstPad:src: caps = "NULL"
Freeing pipeline ...
```

I have tried too many other pipelines to put on one post, but I can answer any other questions.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

By now you probably have solved that problem, but still here's an idea: `text/uri-list` indicates that you didn't hand an actual stream to `gstreamer`, but rather a (textual) playlist that contains stream addresses. I guess `gstreamer` can't handle those, hence you need to parse them beforehand and then hand an actual audio stream address to it.

Comment: Actually I think I ended up using VLC, which had other problems. And then the project kind of fell apart, I graduated, and it has since been disassembled and recycled. Thanks for the answer though!